# I get duplicate claims from IdentityServer in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

Any ideas how this is possible? I really can't figure this out.
I've been trying to solve it, but I ended with no results.. I expected only to have a single role 'admin'..

[image: Duplicate claims]

Comment: What does the ID-token and access token look like?

Comment: @ToreNestenius I haven't used 'AddAuthentication' and then AddJwtBearer in my IdentityServer. If I do this in another application, everything works as expected and I only see a single role (same for the access token, only a single role is present in that other application). However, if I try to use an Authorize attribute on one of my methods above a controller within my IdentityServer, suddenly when I try to inspectate the User.Claims, I see that there is a duplicate role?

Comment: For within IdentityServer, I have no idea why you have duplicates, perhaps you have diplicates in the user database?

Comment: No, I checked. A user just have a single role claim which is as expected. I'm clueless as well... I do not even send additional role claim through my AddOpenIdAuthentication and still duplicates are present?

Comment: `If I do this in another application, everything works as expected` then maybe a rebuild would help? it looks like something be ached in visual studio? have you tried to copy your problematic project to run in another different machine?

Comment: This is not like that, it has to do with configuring the connection for OpenID. That is what I meant with 'other application'.. Is has nothing to do with copying stuff to another machine, rather I was more referencing to configuration settings. Usually, you use AddAuthentication(....).AddJwtBearer() when you want to protect your APIs, then this configuration works fine. If you want to do this directly within IdentityServer, suddenly when using Authorize attribute then I get duplicate roles...

Comment: then I'm afraid that you have to provide more code so that other communities can reproduce the issue and troubleshoot... it looks like not a normal issue. just like you said we can't find similar problem online..